True magnetic levitation with permanent magnets only
I am aware of (and believe, even though I can't myself derive the conclusion) the Earnshaw's theorem that says that true levitation using only permanent magnets is impossible, I'm more like looking for an explanation in what ways would a particular setup be unstable (by true levitation I mean that the levitating object is not being mechanically supported or restrained in any way, and also not requiring any active control or motion of any part of the system, like spin-stabilization. Obviously, no superconductors too, just permanent magnets). The idea is as follows:
I was thinking about a sphere completely covered in small magnets all pointing with like poles outwards (sort of magnetic disco-ball), and a flat floor also covered with magnets facing the same poles up - would such a ball float above the floor? At least in theory, ignoring manufacturing imperfections? I. e., would it be stable in the vertical direction?
If the floor had a circular shape with the edges curved upwards (creating a hollow "bowl"), could it prevent the ball from rolling off of it? That is, if it would float above the surface in the first place.
On the face of it, it looks like the disco-ball would always present like poles closest to the magnets in the floor, so should produce a net repulsive force. But I can't work out all the forces as many of the magnets on the ball would be oriented at various different angles relative to the floor, and I suspect this would be the bane of the setup.
What do you think? I would be quite surprised if this hasn't been demonstrated in some experiment already.

With such a floor, you would get a uniform magnetic field. With a ball equal numbers of magnets are pointing up and down. So it would not levitate. You might think about a floor and a flat plate.

@mmesser314 Thank you, but I'm not sure I understand... yes, with the ball, equal numbers of magnets are pointing up and down but the like poles are closer to the floor. Of course, on the "up" side of the ball, the other pole is closer to the floor, but that happens way higher above the floor overall so the attractive force should not be as strong to cancel out the repulsive force from the magnets pointing down. My understanding is that the floor would not produce a uniform magnetic field, but the field would get weaker the higher you are above the floor.

It might help to think of electric fields. The electric field and electrostatic force get weaker as you get farther from a point charge. But for a flat plate as in a capacitor, the field is uniform. The force on a test charge does not get weaker with distance. Gravity would be the same.

@mmesser314 I am not familiar with the bit about uniform field above a flat plate - surely the field must be getting weaker the further you are from the plate and can't go on in the same strength forever. What would the situation be if the floor was a single large diameter magnet instead?

This might help - How is it physically possible that the electric field of some charge distributions does not attenuate with the distance?
